# Where for Enum Conversion

Tags: rust

In my code I want to convert an Enum value to an `i8`.
Now to allow arbitrary Enums I am not sure how to express the necessary type constraints.

```rust
pub struct Overrides {
    overrides: HashMap<i8, Box<dyn Any>>,
}

impl Overrides {
    pub fn get_option<V, E>(&self, i: E) -> Option<V> where E: Into<i8> {
        self.overrides.get(&(i as i8));
        None
    }
```

Just specifying `Into` seems not enough.

Comment: From a glance `get_option` seems difficult to write assuming it is intended to give the value contained in the box, at least without a `Copy` or `Clone` bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I fell back to using macros:

```rust
pub struct Overrides {
    overrides: HashMap<i8, Box<dyn Any>>,
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! get_option {
    ( $self:expr, $x:expr ) => {
        {
            $self.get_option($x as i8)
        }
    };
}

impl Overrides {
    pub fn get_option<V>(&self, i: i8) -> Option<V> {
        self.overrides.get(&i);
        None
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

[`as`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/keyword.as.html) conversions can only perform coercions and [an explicit list of casts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions). If you want to rely on the `Into` implementation of `i`'s type, you need to use [`Into::into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into).

```
pub struct Overrides {
    overrides: HashMap<i8, Box<dyn Any>>,
}

impl Overrides {
    pub fn get_option<V>(&self, i: impl Into<i8>) -> Option<V> {
        self.overrides.get(&i.into());
        None
    }
}
```

I've written this with [impl Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html); you could also just have the bound on `E` without using `where`. All are equivalent.

Comment: And is there a way to keep the `as`?

Comment: @abergmeier Why?

Comment: Would prefer this to just accept Enums.

Comment: Also, Enum does not impement `Into`